# The value of the same preprocessor directive is correct in one file and wrong in another

Tags: c, makefile, preprocessor-directive

I have a header file with pre-processor directive defined as follows:

```
#define X 10
#define Y 5
#define DIV (X/Y)
```

Now I have two different C files that I have included this header in.
When I print the value of this in these two files, the value is different! The program is pretty big and there are multiple preprocessor Macros that are being used.

C file #1
Value of DIV is 2

C file #2 
Value of DIV is 8!

Why is this happening? This is the first time I have ever encountered such an error. Is this an error with the compiler or the make file?

Is it because there is DIV defined in another header? or is there a much deeper problem?

----------------- Edited ----------------- More Info:

It turns out DIV itself has not been defined at many places. But X and Y have been in different folders of the parent directory in which a lot of apps exist.

a. Evertime I do >make; I assume that the value of the preprocessor directives are recalculated?

b. Can one of the dependencies in the make file be at fault? If one of the dependencies has a different header file with x, Y defined?

c. How does the compilation of a preprocessor directive behave in case of a complex folder structure that has multiple headers in different directories with X and Y defined?

```
|_ Child 1
  |_ INC
    |_ Header 2 with x and y defined
  |_ Program 1 -> Has Header 2 included. X and Y defined.
|_ Child 2
  |_ INC
     |_ Header1 - Has X, Y & DIV defined
  |_ Program 2 -> Has Header 1 included. Value of DIV calculated using X, Y of which header?
  |_ Program 3 -> Has Header 1 included. Whats value of X, Y and DIV? Is it recalculated?
```

Right now the value of DIV is fine in one of the programs and wrong in another!

Comment: Sounds to me like DIV is getting redefined. Try setting DIV to 2 and re-running your test

Comment: When I set manually set the value to 2 the value remains so in both the files. Does this for sure mean that it is being redefined?

Comment: We would need to see more of the code (i.e. where the DIV macro is being called and how its being used) to determine why you are receiving two different values for what is suppose to be the same macro.

Comment: Try putting making DIV be `#define DIV(X,Y) ((X)/(Y))` and see how that changes things.

Comment: @RussSchultz: Let me try out this. I just changed the name of DIV to DIV_1 and its fixed for now. But its not a good fix. I would like to understand more about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a bug in make or the compiler. It's an error in your Makefile or your expectations. Sadly, the information you provide is confusing and next to useless. First, identifiers in C are case sensitive. You sometimes use x, sometimes X. That's not very diligent.

The expansion of C macros depend on the sequence of `#define` and `#undef` directives in the exact sequence, controlled by the sequence of `-Idirectory` options. Macros may also be set with the `-DX=...` option, overriding whatever is in a header. You don't show us the actual command line that gets executed to make a judgement. For starters,

```
 find . -name '*.h' | xargs grep 'define.*X'
```

should give a clue where to look for definitions of `X`.

Comment: "controlled by the sequence of `-Idirectory` options" - it would be more accurate to say something like "controlled by the order that headers are `#include`ed, and searched for in the sequence of `-Idirectory` options" :)

Comment: @Jens: Sorry about that. The identifier is in the same case at all places. I will edit it. The Make file has around 6 include directories with about 10 dependencies. Thank you for the info. I will look into all the include directories.